# Text view goes beyond the background image android why?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

This is my problem:

[image]

As you can see that message background is too small for the text. How can I make it bigger to encapsulate the textview ?
I should make an ImageView ? Or can I set a width and height to the background?
This is the message content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.rcrisan.bocterinomore.MessageActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_message">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/messageContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/received"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/receivedIcon"
            android:text="@string/messages"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:includeFontPadding="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/sentIcon"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/messages" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What kind of drawable is this?

Comment: Action bar and tab icon category, png format

Comment: Your problem might be the PNG. Those and JPEG files can't be resized in anyway. It appears as is. I suggest you try either __9-Patches__ or __Shapes drawable__. Those can resize to fit your `Views`